# Android Password GUI

Tags: android

I am looking for Android GUI which is wheel type number lock, with numbers on the wheel. The password GUI looks like a wheel with numbers on it and user can roll the wheel to select a number when wheel stops, only the numbers are visible that are on the surface of wheel.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a standard dialog available in the Android SDK so you'll have to write your own.

The closest thing in the Android SDK is the `NumberPicker` but sadly this is not part of the public SDK so shouldn't be used in your applications.  You could have a [look at the source](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/com/android/internal/widget/NumberPicker.java;h=ae08eca1155119cec6e5ed285f3db341b5bad9bc;hb=HEAD) to give your some ideas though.